# Character Recognition library

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to recognize characters (Alphanumeric) from an image using any library in  Java/Android ? For eg. If I click a photo of a pizza bill

```
             Pizza Hut 

       Simple Cheese   $4.00
```

I want it to return a text 'Pizza',' Hut ' ,'Simple ',' Cheese','$4.00'.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaOCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/) might be a thing you want to look at

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). I think it was originally developed by Google but is now open source and fairly widely used.